# Длина INT в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Ставлю для `user_id` длину *int* = 1000000 и появляется следующая ошибка:

> #1439 - Display width out of range for column 'user_id' (max = 255)

Это означает, что больше 255 пользователей у меня не может быть? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

255 в данном случае — это длина целого (количество десятичных разрядов).

двумястами пятьюдесятью пятью десятичными цифрами можно выразить число 10 в 255 степени, для которого даже официального названия [не придумано](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).

это **очень большое** число.

вам же я порекомендую использовать просто `int`, без указания количества разрядов. примерно так:

```
create table ... (user_id int, ...) ...;
```